# Priority encoder

Tags: encoder

I want to implement a priority encoder with 3 inputs. I know that an encoder takes <=2^n inputs and n outputs and i was thinking if this is possible(this was an exam question and it seems strange to me)?

Comment: Possible what? To implement an encoder? It's 21st century out there.

Comment: to draw the scheme of an encoder with 3 inputs

Comment: Yes it is possible. Will we do it for you? Probably not.

Comment: how because if it takes 3 inputs how many outputs it has?

Comment: It can't take three inputs. It can take 4 and ignore one of them.

Comment: the question says clear that it takes 3 inputs. i dont understand. that is what makes no sense. the teacher wanted 3 inputs not 4 and ignore one

Comment: The  *ignore* part is in your implementation. You can connect it to a constant `0`.

Comment: ok but when you say that one is connected to a constant i see it an an constant input which makes it an input too. so there are 4 inputs even if one of them is constant it is clearly an input. he asked for 3 not 4 with one connected to a constant. but thnx for clarification that only 3 inputs is not possible

Comment: Draw a black box around the implementation including the constant and suddenly you will discover that there are 3 inputs to this box.

Comment: and 1 in the box:)).

Comment: That's OK if you are kidding now. If you are not - I give up.

Comment: last comment was kidding.the others were not.

Comment: @OtnielMercea please learn how to ask questions http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask if you want your questions answered then stay on topic http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Be a part of the community and write good questions, and by good questions, I mean questions that are on-topic, are not broad, and where you show your work. Thanks

Comment: and how i was off topic? and you didnt see my work? i have a question and i proposed a solution which turned out to be wrong. are you blind or what? i was on the topic on which i wrote and i came with a solution that was wrong and i needed someone to guide me so what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, this is possible.

A priority encoder encodes a number of discrete *inputs*, into a *binary code*. It does not matter much how you represent the output, and there's no problem having one or more unused state. Think of all the [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) encoders, encoding from 10 inputs to 4 outputs.

You mention that you have \$2^N\$ inputs and \$N\$ outputs. That's not strictly necessary. You can have \$K\$ inputs and \$\lceil\log_2 K\rceil\$ outputs. Unless \$K\$ is a power of two, some states will never be seen on the output pins.

Comment: i said that i have 2 to the power of n inputs and n outputs not n to the power of 2 inputs

Comment: @OtnielMercea No you didn't. You said "I want to implement a priority encoder _with 3 inputs_." You also said you know an encoder has 2^n inputs, which is false.

Comment: and then i posted the 'rule' that i know. maybe there are more. he didnt teach us . and an encoder has <=2 ^n. i did a mistake in the post

Comment: i corrected my mistake. i didnt see your 'rule' elsewhere and my 'rule'  i am not sure if is correct. this is why i posted the question.

Comment: @OtnielMercea Here's a real existing part with 10 inputs and 4 outputs, the good old [74147](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls147.pdf). May be useful if you want to see how they work.

Comment: i dont understand anything anymore. if you look at one of my  post you will see another stupid question in the same exam which makes no sense. if you look at this question and apply the 'rule' which he told us it makes no sense. if i look at what you posted i see something different.i think i will give up. thx anyway for help and time.

Comment: What don't you understand? The 3 input encoder will output `0` for \$D_0\$ asserted, `1` for \$D_1\$ asserted, `2` for \$D_2\$ asserted. That's all. It will *never* output `3` (or perhaps will for none asserted - depending on the requirements). Now draw the truth table.

Comment: yes but 2^n==3 and from this n is approx 1.59... Pls conform my 'rule' draw an encoder which have 1 output wire and half wire output. that is what i cannot understand.

Comment: @OtnielMercea That's why I added the ceiling. 1.59 rounds up to 2 physical pins.

Comment: you added ceiling. our teacher didn't. and during exam what you do when your teacher taught you stupid 'rules'  and you have to do it?

Comment: i only wanted to clarify in my head some things. if i don't understand or the course is stupid. thx anyway for your response

Comment: Do you understand the answer? It is the correct one.

Comment: the answer i understand NOW. after i learned that what i knew were STUPID THINGS AND FLAWED. maybe someday the school will change.until then Stack Exchange rocks.:))

Comment: @OtnielMercea Try to read your course material again. It might start making sense now.

Comment: thx. if you are interested i have another post with a latch where i didnt get a clear answer. if you can and want pls respond me on that thing too.